# Why does the else condition of my if-statement not work?

Tags: ruby, class, if-statement, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a tic-tac-toe program. The problem I am experiencing is that in my `if` statement, which allows the user enter his/her desired coordinate, my `else` condition is not working. The `else` condition is in place in case the user enters a coordinate not on the board.

This is my code:

```
class Game

  def initialize
    @board=Array.new
    @board[1]="1  __|"
    @board[2]="__"
    @board[3]="|__"
    @board[4]="\n2  __|"
    @board[5]="__"
    @board[6]="|__"
    @board[7]="\n3    |"
    @board[8]="  "
    @board[9]="|  "
    @turn="o"
    @win_status = false
  end

  def turn
    @turn
  end

  def show_board
    puts "   1  2  3"
    @board.each do |i|
      print i
    end
    puts ""
  end

  def set_turn #switches turns
    if @turn == "x"
      @turn = "o"
    else @turn == "o"
      @turn = "x"
    end
  end

  def make_move
    puts "Enter x coordinate"
    x=gets.to_i
    puts "Enter y coordinate"
    y=gets.to_i
    if y==1 && x==1
      @board[1]="1  _"+@turn+"|"
    elsif y==2 && x==1
      @board[2]="_"+@turn
    elsif  y==3 && x==1
      @board[3]="|_"+@turn
    elsif y==1 && x==2
      @board[4]="\n2  _"+@turn+"|"
    elsif y==2 && x==2
      @board[5]="_"+@turn
    elsif y==3 && x==2
      @board[6]="|_"+@turn
    elsif y==1 && x==3
      @board[7]="\n3   "+@turn+"|"
    elsif y==2 && x==3
      @board[8]=" "+@turn
    elsif y==3 && x==3
      @board[9]="| "+@turn+" \n"
    else
      "You entered an invalid coordinate"
    end

  end

  def win_combo
    return [[@board[1][4] + @board[2][1] + @board[3][2]], [@board[4][5] + @board[5][1] + @board[6][2]], [@board[7][5] + @board[8][1] + @board[9][2]],[@board[1][4] + @board[4][5] + @board[7][5]], [@board[2][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[8][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[6][2] + @board[9][2]], [@board[1][4] + @board[5][1] + @board[9][2]], [@board[3][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[7][5]]]
  end

  def check_win
    #if some row or column or diagonal is "xxx" or "ooo" then set @win_status = true
    self.win_combo.each do |arr|
      str = arr.join
      if str == "xxx"
        puts "X Wins!"
        return true
      elsif str == "ooo"
        puts "O Wins!"
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end
  g = Game.new
  while g.check_win != true
    g.show_board
    g.set_turn
    g.make_move
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just returning the string: "You entered an invalid coordinate".

I suspect that you want to display it using:

```
puts "You entered an invalid coordinate"
```

Otherwise it is passed as the result of `g.make_move` and then ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you would like to print: "You entered an invalid coordinate" to the console in the event of an invalid x, y coordinate. You need to add a method to that statement like:

```
else
  puts "You entered an invalid coordinate"
end
```

Or:

```
else
  abort "You entered an invalid coordinate"
end
```

Comment: `abort` would be very heavy-handed. Looping until the user enters an acceptable coordinate would be kinder and gentler.

Comment: good call. would doing a couple while loops till the inputs are valid do the trick or would you recommend a more efficient way.

Comment: I'd use a simple `loop` ... `until` with a test for valid conditions as the exit criteria to start and then build upon that. People fat-finger numeric entries all the time, so the X/Y entry could be invalid, but so would trying to use a cell that's already been assigned to, so both should be checked at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you you forgot to use `puts` or `print` in front of your `"You entered an invalid coordinate"` string. As it is currently written it is returned from the method.

In Ruby, the return value of a method is the value [returned by the last statement evaluated](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Return_Values). For example, both of these methods will return the same value if `x=3`:

```
def square_example(x)
  if x ==3
    x_squared = 9
  end
end


def square_example2(x)
  if x == 3
    x_squared = 9
  end
  return x_squared
end
```

For simplicity of testing you might try using explicit returns so that you can easily tell what it is you are returning from the method. Or (as a beginner with Ruby myself) you could add in a `puts` statement with each `if/else` result so that you can easily monitor the results of each move and then remove those `puts` lines when you know everything is working properly.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is a misinterpretation of the site below, but if you're interested in the difference between 'and' and '&&' you should check out the comments below.
From: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

You will want to use "and" instead of "&&", an example:

```
if y==1 and x==1
    # do move
elsif y==2 and x==1
    # do move
.
.
.
else
    "invalid coordinate"
end
```

The "&&" operator will check that the values on either side of it are nonzero. If they are both nonzero then it will return true. In your case it is doing the operation

```
false && false
```

Where false != 0, so it returns true.

Here is another discussion of this: http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=27353

Comment: `and` and `&&` differ only in order of precedence, `&&` being higher, so in some situations you would need parenthesis with `and`, but not with `&&`.  That's not an issue here--you could use either. In `a && b` (or `and`), Ruby checks `a`.  If it evaluates `false` (i.e., `false` or `nil`, nothing else), it returns `false`, and doesn't even check `b`. If `a` is true it returns the logical value of `b`. Some Ruby coders like `and` (where precedence is not an issue) because they believe it reads better; others always use `&&`, it part to reduce the chance of being bit by a precedence problem.

Comment: +1 @CarySwoveland. Being bit by the precedence bug can be very tough to find and fix. Some of us use `&&` and `||` along with parenthesis to visually demonstrate what we want, and to force the interpreter to do exactly what we want rather than rely on the order-of-precedence which can change when we move between languages.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification! Many apologies to anyone who was confused by this. Seems I just misread the ruby logic operator site that I posted.